# Streaming Tweets with LinqToTwitter C#

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

Is it possible to get the list of tweets of a twitter user in real-time using LinqToTwitter in C#

Following is the code i use to get the tweets of a user without real-time streaming.

```
   var rawTwitterItems = twitterContext.Status.Where(x => x.ScreenName == "BloombergNews" && x.Type == StatusType.User);
   var items= a.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, LinqToTwitter does support streaming. See the documentation example on streaming [users status messages](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Stream%20User%20Messages&referringTitle=Streaming%20Twitter%20Content):

```
Console.WriteLine("\nStreamed Content: \n");
int count = 0;

await
    (from strm in twitterCtx.Streaming
     where strm.Type == StreamingType.User
     select strm)
    .StartAsync(async strm =>
    {
        string message = 
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(strm.Content) ? 
                "Keep-Alive" : strm.Content;
        Console.WriteLine(
            (count + 1).ToString() + 
            ". " + DateTime.Now + 
            ": " + message + "\n");

        if (count++ == 5)
            strm.CloseStream();
    });
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but how to tell that to only to get tweets from a specific account(for example i am using "BloombergNews")

Comment: @VibeeshanRC The Twitter API makes this available only to the authenticated user. If you have that user's credentials, then authorize as that user. You can view documentation and download samples on the LINQ to Twitter Web site: http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/.